# latency analysis HTTPs(w/ two way SSL) using curl

Tags: ssl, curl, https, analysis, latency

To find latency HTTPs w/ "two way SSL", I used curl as belows

```
curl -w "
time_namelookup=%{time_namelookup}\n
time_connect=%{time_connect}\n
time_appconnect=%{time_appconnect}\n
time_pretransfer=%{time_pretransfer}\n
time_starttransfer=%{time_starttransfer}\n
time_total=%{time_total}\n"
-k --cert ./file.crt.pem --key ./file.key.pem -X POST -d '
----
time_namelookup=0.003
time_connect=0.174
time_appconnect=0.629
time_pretransfer=0.629
time_starttransfer=1.649
time_total=1.649
```

As you can see, time difference between appconnect/pretransfer and starttransfer is quite large. But my application logs says processing time is quite smaller than 1.020s(1.649-0.629).
So my guess is "appconnect" indicates the timing client-> server SSL connection is done but doesn't includes server -> client SSL connection.
Can you confirm that my guess is correct?
Or how can I breakdown client->server, server -> client SSL handshake latency, respectively?

Comment: Your question is probably more on topic for [sf] or [webmasters.se] as it is not related to programming which is the topic here.

Comment: From documentation: *time_appconnect
                             The time, in seconds, it took from the start until the SSL/SSH/etc connect/handshake to the remote host was completed. (Added in 7.19.0)*  so yes it does include all TLS handshake time which is bidirectional so there is no split client->server/server->client as you seem to think.